# bind is not working in safari 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm using safari 5.1.1 in my system and my application is also running in safari 5.1.1. In my application i'm using window resize event with bind method. Its working fine all other browsers like ie, chrome,firefox but it doesn't work in safari 5.1.1 and less. whenever its run it will through an exception as `'"undefined" is not a function({....}.bind(this);...'`.
I have searched more about this issue but i din't found any solutions to recover this issue.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     alert("resized");
     ...My code goes 'this' here....
}.bind(this));
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
KarthiK

Comment: Please post complete code Jerry Kartik :-)

Comment: @Pilot i have updated my post with sample code.

Comment: are you sure you getting this error coz of resize ? I dont see any issue over there

Comment: try `window.onresize = function { alert("resized") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error most likely comes from `.bind(this)`. As you see in the [MDN docs about Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), safari supports bind in versions >= 5.1.4.

You can use [`jQuery.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead.

```
var resizeHandler = function() { alert('resized'); };
$(window).resize($.proxy(resizeHandler, this));
```

Did not test the example but it should look like this.